# Python Beginner : Extract a specific each row from CSV file and write it to different CSV files

Tags: python, csv, pandas, row, extract

I have a .csv file with 40 lines of a weather station data, which is similar to this:

```
Date        Station                  PET  Max Temp  Min Temp

2/11/2016   Conroe                   0.09   70       33
2/11/2016   Huntsville               0.11   69       33
2/11/2016   Overton                  0.14   67       34
2/11/2016   Allen                    0.11   71       32
2/11/2016   Dallas AgriLife Center   0.17   71       37
2/11/2016   Forney                   0.13   70       35
```

I'm trying to extract data of each station from this file using pandas and write it to different .csv files for each station.

I've tried using this code:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Desktop\\report.csv')

for Station in df:
    df[Station].to_csv('C:\\data\\'+ Station +'.csv')
```

But this code is extracting the data by each column like this,[image of files created](https://i.stack.imgur.com/phGv9.jpg)

please help me with this...
instead of writing all the data elements, is there a way to iterate through row by row and extract the data i.e like looping through each row and create a CSV file for each station.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`df[Station]` Simply selects the column. What you want to do it the following:
In pseudo code:

```
for each station in stations:
    select the row and put it a separate data_frame

when done write each data frame to a file.
```

This is not really hard to achieve in pandas too. Here is how:

```
 for name in df.Station:
   ....:     print df[df.Station == name]
   ....:     
        Date Station   PET  Max Temp  Min Temp
0  2/11/2016  Conroe  0.09        70        33
        Date     Station   PET  Max Temp  Min Temp
1  2/11/2016  Huntsville  0.11        69        33
        Date  Station   PET  Max Temp  Min Temp
2  2/11/2016  Overton  0.14        67        34
        Date Station   PET  Max Temp  Min Temp
3  2/11/2016   Allen  0.11        71        32
        Date                 Station   PET  Max Temp  Min Temp
4  2/11/2016  Dallas AgriLife Center  0.17        71        37
        Date Station   PET  Max Temp  Min Temp
5  2/11/2016  Forney  0.13        70        35
```

This does just a print, but you can replace the print with a write to a new csv:

```
In [54]: for name in df.Station:
   ....:     df[df.Station == name].to_csv(name+'.csv')
   ....:     

In [55]: ls
Allen.csv  Conroe.csv  Dallas AgriLife Center.csv  foo.csv  Forney.csv  Huntsville.csv  Overton.csv  stations.csv
```

Now each of the files contains the data you wish.

Comment: Thank You very much for the help, was struggling for long time to get this..@Oz123

Comment: df[df.Station == name] @Oz123 Hey can you explain what's this specific line doing... thanks..

Comment: It's a filter. You can for example use it for filtering all temperatures above 70 with `df[df.temp > 70]`

Answer (score 1):

```
df =pd.DataFrame({'Date': {0: '2/11/2016', 1: '2/11/2016', 2: '2/11/2016', 3: '2/11/2016', 4: '2/11/2016', 5: '2/11/2016'}, 'PET': {0: 0.089999999999999997, 1: 0.11, 2: 0.14000000000000001, 3: 0.11, 4: 0.17000000000000001, 5: 0.13}, 'Max Temp': {0: 70, 1: 69, 2: 67, 3: 71, 4: 71, 5: 70}, 'Station': {0: 'Conroe', 1: 'Huntsville', 2: 'Overton', 3: 'Allen', 4: 'Dallas Agri Life Center', 5: 'Forney'}, 'Min Temp': {0: 33, 1: 33, 2: 34, 3: 32, 4: 37, 5: 35}})

df.groupby('Station').apply(lambda x : pd.DataFrame.to_csv(x, x['Station'].values[0] + '.csv'))
```

Comment: As there are 49 lines of data on overall,  instead of writing all the data elements, is there a way to iterate through row by row and extract the data i.e like looping through each row and create a CSV file for each station. ?? Thanks.. for the reply @Dickster

Comment: Thanks for the reply @Back2Basics May be my question was bad what I'm trying to do is extract data of each station and create a csv file for each station and write all the columns to it i.e.. [Date Station PET  Max Temp  Min Temp],  thanks..